# gnus-group-make-group error: Duplicate folder name

Tags: gnus

I cannot use `Gnus` anymore because of the following error:

```
gnus-group-make-group: Could not create group on server: NO (ALREADYEXISTS) Duplicate folder name Agenda (Failure)
```

I couldn't find anything about this error on the Web and I have no idea where to remove this duplicate on my computer.

Comment: As a workaround, it has been enough to restart from a clean `~/.gnus.d` (with the drawback I had to resubscribe to the newsgroups I was subscribed to).